# sessionStorage is 1/2 working

Tags: sessionstorage

pag1.php

```
 <div id="guest_name"></div>
<?
//Some code
echo '<script>';
echo 'var guest_name = ' . json_encode($guest_name) . ';';
echo '</script>';
echo "<a href=main.php>Enter</a>";
?>
<script>    
//This works great
   $("#guest_name").text(sessionStorage.getItem("guest_name"));    
</script>
```

when I click on and go to main.php, it stops working!!

```
<div id="guest_name"></div><!--Nothing is shown this div here -->
<script>
$("#guest_name").text(sessionStorage.getItem("guest_name"));  //Does not work!!
</script>
```

main.php is NOT loaded in a new window or a new tab! Thank you

Comment: I am beyond puzzled. Can someone please offer any suggestions at all? Anything to check or look into!!

Comment: Hmmmmm! The information shows up when I go to main.php and ONLY after i hit the reload button??